# If L,M,N are subspaces of V under field F then prove that L ∩ (M+N)=(L∩M)+(L∩N) (also, M ⊆ L)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I understand the question. I have two claims i)  L ∩ (M+N) ⊆ (L∩M)+(L∩N)  and ii) (L∩M)+(L∩N)⊆  L ∩ (M+N)

For the claim ii) Can I proceed with x,y ∈ (L∩M)+(L∩N)such that x+y∈ (L∩M)+(L∩N)
x=a1 + b1 and y= a1- b1 for all a1∈(L∩M) and b1∈ (L∩N)
Can someone tell me if my approach is right? Please give me hints to proceed with the proof!

Answer (score 0):

In general, the equality fails, for instance, when $F=\Bbb R$, $V=\Bbb R^2$, $L=\Bbb R(1,1)$, $M=\Bbb R(1,0)$, and $N=\Bbb R(0,1)$. Then $M+N=\Bbb R^2$, so $L\cap (M+N)=L$. On the other hand $L\cap M=L\cap N=\{0\}$,  so $(L\cap M)+(L\cap N)=\{0\}\ne M+N$.

On the other hand, if $M\subseteq L$ then the quality reduces to $L\cap (M+N)=M+(L\cap N)$. An inclusion $M\cup (L\cap N)\subset L\cap (M+N)$ implies an inclusion $L\cap (M+N)\supseteq M+(L\cap N)$. To show the opposite inclusion let $x\in L\cap (M+N)$ be any element. There exist elements $m\in M$ and $n\in N$ such that $x=m+n$. Then $n=x-m\in L+M=L$. Thus 
$x\in M+(L\cap N)$.